# Resolving a PHP PDO Error: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Found lots of similar problems on this site, but the solutions for those issues don't seem to reply. The user in question has full access to the database, and from what I can tell I'm not missing any commas etc. A second set of eyes would be great.

> Submitted signature is in an acceptable formatTrying to open a connectionError!: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user     'emkinsti_user1'@'localhost' to database 'signatures'

```
<?php
// Tracks what fields have validation errors
$errors    = array();
// Default to showing the form
$show_form = true;

// 1. Get the input from the form
//  Using the PHP filters are the most secure way of doing it
$name   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$output = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'output', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);

// 2. Confirm the form was submitted before doing anything else
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// 3. Validate that a name was typed in
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = true;
}

// 3. Validate that the submitted signature is in an acceptable format
if (!json_decode($output)) {
    $errors['output'] = true;
}
}

// No validation errors exist, so we can start the database stuff
if (empty($errors)) {

echo "Submitted signature is in an acceptable format";"<br/>";

$dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=signatures';
$user = 'emkinsti_user1';
$pass = '6nqq103t26';
}
// 4. Open a connection to the database using PDO
try {
echo "Trying to open a connection";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}

// Make sure we are talking to the database in UTF-8
$db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');

// Create some other pieces of information about the user
// to confirm the legitimacy of their signature
$sig_hash = sha1($output);
$created  = time();
$ip       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


// 5. Use PDO prepare to insert all the information into the database
$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO signatures (signator, signature, sig_hash,    ip, created)
VALUES (:signator, :signature, :sig_hash, :ip, :created)');
$sql->bindValue(':signator', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':signature', $output, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':sig_hash', $sig_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':created', $created, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();

// 6. Trigger the display of the signature regeneration
$show_form = false;
//  mysql_close($db);
$db = null;
?>
```

Comment: The manual states `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);` with a comma after `dbname=test',` <= http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php why not try it that way and see if it does resolve.

Comment: @Fred-ii- He does exactly that, the `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test'` has been put in a `string`, and the comma follows after the variable in `new PDO()`. Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Jordy TBH, I'm not really sure and have simply asked the OP to try it that way and see if it does resolve. If it doesn't, then the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

emkinsti_user1'@'localhost' to database 'signatures'
if you are using CPanel, CPanel uses prefixes also to the database name:

You used: emkinsti_user1 as users.

You should use: emkinsti_signatures as database name.

Log in into your CPanel and there you will find the database name with prefix

Answer (score 0):

Try http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php to see if the database is supported by PDO.

```
<?php
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
?>
```

Just an idea. I would expect another error message when it isn't. So, as far as I can tell, the user has no access when accessing the database from the local host.

Comment: Seems to be more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, clever you. But the code doesn't format well in a comment. Hence the answer. Anyway, I don't think there will be an easy answer, but we'll see.

Comment: He posted it as a comment before, but then deleted it and posted as an answer. Not sure why. @idmean

Comment: Tried your suggestion as well KIKO and I returned: Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => sqlite )

Comment: Yes, I thought it would be supported. But have a closer look at the privileges, you're access the database from the localhost. Is the database on the same server as the webserver? Does the user have permission for localhost?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes it does. I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 as well which was a fix for others. Doesn't get me anywhere though.